# using windows forms execute a .exe file

Tags: vb.net, winforms, node.js

I want  to execute a .exe file which starts my node.js app using windows forms(vb.net) on a button click.
I am using

```
    Process.Start("C:\Users\PROG21\Desktop\chat\start.exe")
```

The problem is it starts the command window and just within 3-4 seconds it automatically closes.Why is that so? This is happening only with Node.js app ,the other .exe files run smoothly through this code.

And also on other button click i want to close the command window terminating the Node.js app.How can i achieve it?

Any help would be appreciated

Cheers
Jeev

Comment: Node script simply returns? (Why do you want to do that?)

Comment: Because evrytime i want to start this node app, i don want to use the command prompt again and again, instead have an form app to start and end this Node app. is this possible?

Comment: How about link, batch / powershell script with `node app.js` or even better — [nodemon](https://github.com/remy/nodemon) (or something similar)?

Comment: It's worth a try.Can u help me out like how to implement this Bat file into my winform.I am totally new into node.js

Comment: Just create link (on desktop) to `node.exe` (which is in `%ProgramFiles%` somewhere), open link's properties, set Working Directory to `C:\Users\PROG21\Desktop\chat` and add `app.js` to Target. Even better: 1) `npm install -g nodemon`; 2) add `"main": "app.js"` to your `package.json`; 3) `cd` into app's root and run `nodemon`.

Comment: What happens if you run `C:\Users\PROG21\Desktop\chat\start.exe` directly? Does it require any arguments?

Comment: it just initiates a Node.js chat app when it is executed directly. and it doesnt need any arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is that you used the command interpreter to get it started from the command line.  Which keeps the window opened after the program terminates.  That doesn't happen when you start it from your own program.

Change the Process.Start() call like this:

```
Process.Start("cmd.exe", "/k C:\Users\PROG21\Desktop\chat\start.exe")
```

The /k option keeps the console window opened after the program completes.

Comment: Any idea how to terminate this command prompt which is opened on another button click.??