# Linking button click in windows form app to a game in unity

Tags: c#, winforms, unity-game-engine

I am making a project in which i want to open and start a game in unity when a button is clicked on a windows form app. So is there a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that you know how to build it: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PublishingBuilds.html

So you need to do 3 (one optional) things:

1. Create an ex executable file. The publish method mentioned above will do that for you
2. (Optional) use a packaging software to create installer. Check the unity forums for one of these
3. Run the executable from windows forms: [using windows forms execute a .exe file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14001922/using-windows-forms-execute-a-exe-file)

```
void btnButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Process.Start("cmd.exe", "/k C:\path_to_game\start.exe")
}
```

Comment: Now I want to get back to the form after a certain score is reached. How do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process) class to bootstrap a new process:

```cs
Process.Start(@"D:\GameLocation\game.exe");
```

This, of course, hinges on the assumption that you have already built the game, and have an executable that you can call.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void Button1_Click(object o, EventArgs eA)
{
Process.Start("C:\\my_unity_game_location\mygame.exe");
}
```

Here `Button1` is the button which is present on your WinForm and `Button1_Click` is the event which is assigned to that `Button1`

Comment: Now I want to get back to the form after a certain score is reached. How do I do it?